# Flutter - Transparent System Navigation Bar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, navigationbar

I want to make the bottom navigation bar transparent in Flutter.

Here's what I tried in my `main.dart`

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // transparent status bar
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I also have this in my main scaffold:

```
extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
extendBody: true,
```

But this is the result:

[image: Flutter iOS Screenshot]

App bar works expected, but not the very bottom.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you applying your background inside Scaffold?

Comment: Did you use 'SafeArea' Widget?

Comment: @Thepeanut Yes, I am.

Comment: @KuKu No I did not.

Answer (score 2):

Will post this as an answer.

Currently you're applying your background inside Scaffold and the Scaffold itself internally applies a SafeArea to the body (this is why your body never reaches the bottom part of the screen).
In order to achieve the result your need - apply the background before the Scaffold. As example:

```dart
DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
    ),
    child: Scaffold(...),
)
```

[image]

Comment: What if I'm not applying a background color but just need things to be drawn beneath it? In my instance, the background color is fine, but I have an inkwell whose splash doesn't move beneath area. Is that just a general limitation of the safearea built into scaffolds?

Comment: @CalebRobinson sorry, I did not understand what you need. Could you please provide some examples? Maybe images.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SafeArea, you can just add bottom: false attribute. the code looks like this:

return Scaffold(
body: SafeArea(
bottom: false,
child: Column(
...